# Install new version of c# windows app with old setting (without overwritting exe.config)

Tags: c#, .net

In my c# windows application, I want to Exclude MyApp.Exe.Config from my Setup
Package as I don't want it to get overwritten during upgrade installation of my application.

If I remove app.config while building the setup, it removes existing app.config on the target machines and if included, it overwrites the existing ones.

I also tried using the ExcludeFilter property on the Project Output group but when I exclude *.config, It removes the config file of previous installation.

So, somebody please suggest some ideas so that I do not need to reset my previous settings in new installation.

Thanks

Comment: What installation creator are you using? The time to do this upgrade is at deployment. You want as little upgrade code as possible in your project.

Comment: Hey Gusdor... I am using Visual Studio 2010 for that. Can you suggest me that type of code pls?